# Proper routing language

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help figuring out how to turn the information from 'rake routes' into the correct path to use with <%= link_to %>.

I have tried everything I know and spent hours trying to research this. I've read the Ruby documentation and I'm just getting more confused. I know this is a simple fix but it has completely eluded me.

```
<li><%= link_to 'Company Dash', tenant_corp_path(tenant_id: :tenant.id, corp_id: params[:corp_id]) %></li>
```

Rake routes show the tenant_corp_path GET as follows:
/tenants/:tenant_id/corps/:id(.:format).

How do I properly turn that into a tenant_corp_path statement?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Post your routes and view and controller

Comment: resources :user_corps
  resources :tenants do
    resources :corps do
      get 'users', on: :member
      put 'add_user', on: :member
      delete 'users'
    end

    resource :subscription
    resource :card
    resource :charges
  end

  resources :corps

Comment: It's not picking up the tenant_id. It keeps saying it's 'nil'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use `id` instead of `corp_id` based on the URL you posted. Try:

```
tenant_corp_path(tenant_id: tenant.id, id: params[:corp_id])
```

Comment: This threw the following error: undefined local variable or method `tenant' for #<#<Class:0x00007ffa73effd60>:0x00007ffa73efe758>
Did you mean?  tenant_url